# sum specific cells

Tags: google-sheets

How can you sum specific cells?

When I add up specific cells such as `A10:B20:C30` I get the entire column which doubles the figures.

It is picking up the specific values plus the individual columns

Answer (score 1):

As [Tedinoz](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/196152) and [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163) mentioned, you mixed up the operator for ranges, which is the colon **`:`** , with the separator for a list, which is either a comma **`,`** or a semicolon **`;`** depending on your locale.

Depending on your locale, one of the following will work:

- `=SUM(A10, B20, D30)`
    <sub>OR</sub>
- `=SUM(A10; B20; D30)`